# Partition lattice-maximal chains

Tags: combinatorics

Show that the number of maximal chains in the partition lattice $\prod _n$ is
equal to $\dfrac{(n-1)!n!}{2^{n-1}}$.

I showed that $\prod _n$ is graded lattice, so all maximal chains has the same lenght. It is also geometric lattice.
I don't how to find number of maximal chains in $\prod _n$. I need help.

Answer (score 1):

The maximal chains in the partition lattice correspond to the different ways in which you can start with all elements as singletons and successively merge them in $n-1$ steps until you reach the partition consisting of the entire set. In the step where you have $k$ sets left, there are $\binom k2$ ways to choose two sets to merge. The given formula is the product of these factors over all $n-1$ steps.